# Limitless switching between DVD regions on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook, dvd, regional-settings

Is there a safe way to remove the limit (6?) of DVD region switching on the MacBook Pro?  I'm a  multi-region kind of guy and this 'feature' dives me nuts.  On the interwebs I see many 'tools' that scare me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reflash the DVD drive's firmware to make it region-free,

http://forum.rpc1.org/portal.php

I've used this on a Macbook Pro without any issue, but be cautious, and make triply sure you use the right firmware for your drive

Comment: My driver version is not listed, and I've submitted my firmware dump.  Hopefully something will come of this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) to play DVD's, I believe it ignores region (although I don't have the means to check)

Comment: No go...it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) should let you get around the region limitations in software.

As far as the switching goes, that is a **hardware-based** limitation, and no, you can not change it.

Comment: Just because it is hardware based does not mean it is not possible.  See dbr's answer.

Comment: Additionally, VLC cannot get around it.  I've tried.

Comment: VLC used to be able to get around it. I was able to do so with Tiger, but I can't get it to work with Leopard.