# Disabling the Driver Region on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, dvd, regional-settings

So, this is the first time I try to watch a DVD disc on my (new) Mac and I wonder if I can keep it as fresh-new by **not choosing [any](https://superuser.com/questions/5964/how-do-i-make-my-blu-ray-hd-dvd-dvd-drive-multi-region)** region and [just play discs from anywhere](https://superuser.com/questions/116/limitless-switching-between-dvd-regions-on-macbook-pro).

I understand the media industry made that lock for copyright and whatever, but do I absolutely have to choose a region to be able to play disks, even if I got original ones from different places? Why can I "change region" just 5 times, why even allowing changing?

*(new)* **In other words**: How *much* would it cost us, end users, to have a region free DVD player?

Also, on a side-note, I wonder how to disable the regular DVD Player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I would verify that the disk actually works in *something*. Either a standalone DVD player or another computer, it doesn't matter just *something*.

Next I would attempt to rip it off the disk using [Mac the Ripper](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14414). Try different regional settings.

If you can't find anything else that will play it, and you can't rip it, the disks themselves might be bad.

> ### Standalone DVD players
>
> Usually a configuration flag is set in each player's firmware at the
>   factory. This flag holds the region
>   number that the machine is allowed to
>   play. Region-free players are DVD
>   players shipped without the ability to
>   enforce regional lockout (usually by
>   means of a chip that ignores any
>   region coding), or without this flag
>   set.
>
> However, if the player is not
>   region-free, it can often be unlocked
>   with an unlock code entered via the
>   remote control. This code simply
>   allows the user to change the
>   factory-set configuration flag to
>   another region, or to the special
>   region "0". Once unlocked this way,
>   the DVD player allows the owner to
>   watch DVDs from any region. Many
>   websites exist on the Internet
>   offering these codes, often known
>   informally as hacks. Many websites
>   provide instructions for different
>   models of standalone DVD players, to
>   hack, and their factory codes.
>
> ### Computer DVD drives
>
> Older DVD drives use RPC-1 ("Regional Playback Control")
>   firmware, which means the drive allows
>   DVDs from any region to play. Newer
>   drives use RPC-2 firmware, which
>   enforces the DVD region coding at the
>   hardware level. These drives can often
>   be reflashed or hacked with RPC-1
>   firmware, effectively making the drive
>   region-free. However, this usually
>   voids the warranty.
>
> In most computer drives, users are
>   allowed to change the region code
>   (i.e. change region code) up to five
>   times. However, if the number of
>   allowances reaches zero, the region
>   last used will be permanent even if
>   the drive is transferred to another
>   computer. This limit is built into the
>   drive's controller software, called
>   firmware. Resetting the firmware count
>   can be done with first- or third-part
>   software tools, or by reflashing (see
>   above) to RPC-1 firmware
>
> ### Software DVD players
>
> Most freeware and open source DVD players, such as VLC, ignore region
>   coding. Most commercial players are
>   locked to a region code, but can be
>   easily changed with software.
>
> Other software, known as DVD region
>   killers, transparently remove (or
>   hide) the DVD region code from the
>   software player. Some can also work
>   around locked RPC-2 firmware.

From [Wikipedia article on Region Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code#Implementations_of_region_codes)

Comment: The disk works. I don't want to rip it, I just want to play. And I want to play disks from anywhere. I understand the media industry is restrictive, but why can't I have a "region-less" player?

Answer (score 4):

Open System Preferences and click `CDs & DVDs`. Next to `When you insert a video DVD`, pick `Open Other Application` or `Ignore`. VLC is an all-purpose player which will likely work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks, love VLC, but that answers just half the question. VLC can't read my DVD and I think it might be related to the DVD not having any region selected. DVD Player says it would be first time I'd select one.

Comment: As mentioned in the other question you linked to VLC is not region specific.

Comment: @Grammar well neither VLC or Boxee or Movist can open it, and it's not a problem on the DVD disc neither on the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Region lockouts are performed in the drive's firmware and disassembling that is more than likely illegal.

Comment: There's nothing on superuser FAQ advising to only ask or answer lawfully.

Comment: Is there anything about investing five seconds worth of your time researching your problem before posting yet another thread?

Comment: You mean question? We don't have any threads here. :)

Comment: Ok this isn't on the FAQ, but it should be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq/7935#7935 . And this is for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs . The next link says a lot about what SO is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/9758#9758 I'll quote the most relevant part: *The Trilogy is supposed to be* ***A long term repository of searchable, free, and freely editable information***